# Como obter data e hora em colunas diferentes através de um select Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um problema preciso filtrar uma consulta nas seguintes condições :
tenho o campo Data e tenho o campo hora ambos em varchar , quando tento fazer a consulta como esta:
ex:

```
     select Serial, Latitude,Longitude,Data,Hora from [CheckPoint]
     where Data BETWEEN '20150417' and '20150418'
     and Serial= '120904'
     and Hora BETWEEN '10:00' and '10:00' order by Hora
```

a consulta me retorna nula;
teria alguma possibilidade de manipular esses campos em varchar ?
Se esses campos data e hora fossem do tipo datetime com certeza ficaria bem mais simples a query de consulta.

Comment: Ja tentou converter os dados?

Comment: o campo data e hora sao colunas diferentes, eles nao estao no formato datetime

Comment: Os dados são sempre do mesmo tamanho? Ex. Data tem 8 dígitos e Hora 5?

Comment: `BETWEEN '10:00' and '10:00'` - *BETWEEN* entre **horas iguais**?

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates sim. mesmo tamanho!

Comment: @ramaral between com os dois valores iguais é a mesma coisa de igualar o campo desejado. teria uma forma de fazer outro filtro???

Comment: Só perguntei porque não é usual fazer um BETWEEN entre algo que não tem nada entre(BETWEEN). Podia ser essa a razão da *query* não retornar nada. A forma normal de fazer é `and Hora = '10:00'`

Comment: Seria mais fácil ajudar se colocasse, na pergunta, um exemplo com meia dúzia de registos existentes na tabela.

Comment: @HansMiller , você consegue ver fisicamente no banco se esta consulta realmente retorna registros?

Comment: Se você postar a estrutura da tabela(tipo de dados das colunas) e alguns registos consegue-se ver se a *query* está correta. O facto da ela retornar *null*, por si só, não indica que esteja mal, pode não haver registos que a satisfaça.

Comment: @HansMiller pode responder ?

Answer (score 2):

Você não deve tratar data e hora separados, deve concatená-los ao filtrar por eles. No seu exemplo, o SGBD tentará trazer os registros entre as datas "17/04/2015" e "18/04/2015", ok, dois dias de intervalo. Mas quando você adiciona, separadamente, a condição entre as horas "10:00" e "10:00". Como não existe nenhuma hora entre 10:00 e 10:00, não vem nenhum registro.

Se você deseja trazer registros entre "17/04/2015 10:00" e "18/04/2015 10:00".

Tente assim:

```
DECLARE @DataInicial AS VARCHAR(10); DECLARE @DataFinal AS VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @HoraInicial AS VARCHAR(5); DECLARE @HoraFinal AS VARCHAR(5);
SET @DataInicial = '20150417';SET @DataFinal = '20150418';
SET @HoraInicial = '10:00';SET @HoraFinal = '10:00';

SELECT
    Serial, Latitude,Longitude,Data,Hora
FROM [CheckPoint]
WHERE Data >= CAST(@DataInicial + ' ' + @HoraInicial AS DATETIME) 
AND   Data <= CAST(@DataFinal + ' ' + @HoraFinal AS DATETIME)
AND Serial= '120904'
ORDER BY Hora
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que crie uma terceira coluna do tipo Date, onde o valor default seja um `CAST(Data +' '+ Hora)`. Assim vc terá uma coluna com o tipo certo para fazer seus filtros.

Mas usando o que temos hoje, eu iria na linha do @Silvair, mas como não sou fã de codificar para fazer queries, segue minha sugestão:

```
select T.* 
  from (select Serial, Latitude, Longitude, Data, Hora, CAST(Data +' '+ Hora) as DataHora 
          from [CheckPoint]
         where Serial= '120904') as T
 where T.DataHora BETWEEN '2015-04-17 10:00' and '2015-04-18 10:00'
```